# PC building: Do you have to plug in the 4-pin CPU connector?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, power, connector

My motherboard has a single 4-pin power connector next to the CPU. My power supply has a 8-pin CPU power connector but not a 4 pin one. Instead of going out and buying a 8-to-4 pin CPU power adapter can I just leave this unplugged?

Can't the CPU just use the power from the main ATX connector? I guess it depends on how the motherboard it wired to the CPU but it only seems logical. The PC is for a very small Minecraft server (only about 10 players at once max) so I won't be putting any extreme strain on the CPU or overclocking it.

I have a friend who built a PC and says he didn't plug in any connector for the CPU and just used the ATX connector but that could be a mistake.

I can provide CPU, mobo and PSU specs/model numbers if needed.

**Edit:** When the PC is booted, the fans and status LEDs turn on, but nothing shows on the monitor. Could this be to do with the CPU connector not being plugged in or could it be due to another problem I an suspecting where my setup does not support the CPU internal graphics and requires a graphics card.

Comment: There’s no such thing as a 6-pin CPU power connector. // No, the connector is not optional.

Comment: Sorry. I meant 8-pin.

Comment: I could ask him to double check but my friend claims to have no connector connected to his CPU apart from the ATX connector. Why is this so?

Comment: Perhaps you could share your and your friend's motherboard models?

Comment: Your friend could have a cheap motherboard that doesn't support higher TDP processors, or uses a less durable power supply design. Where you have it available you *should* use the additional connector.

Comment: There are also 8-pin (EPS12V) connectors as well as the 4-pin (ATX12V) connectors. Which you have depends on your motherboard and power supply. https://superuser.com/search?q=4-pin+power+CPU

Comment: What does the motherboard manual say? You can [edit] your question instead of submitting another comment.

Answer (score 1):

Always read the manual carefully guys.
[image: Screenshot from motherboard manual on chapter ATX power connectors]

> DO NOT forget to connect the 4-pin/8-pin ATX +12V power plug. Otherwise, the system will not boot up.